# Upload doesn't start with gsutil

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I'm trying to update my bucket but when I run:

```
gsutil -m cp -r ./public/* gs://<My_BUCKET>/
```

the upload doesn't start, it just output the file list and never start. Output:

```
Copying file://./public/app.js [Content-Type=application/javascript]...
... bunch of files here
/ [0/25 files][    0.0 B/  5.1 MiB]   0% Done
```

Edit: Output with `-D`
It stuck in this:

```
--===============1322370341643520847==--

INFO 0126 09:26:03.228240 base_api.py] Body:
--===============4891318827246988476==
Content-Type: application/json
MIME-Version: 1.0

{"bucket": "staging.bluwave.net", "contentLanguage": "en", "contentType": "application/octet-stream", "name": "terms_files/icon"}
--===============4891318827246988476==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<media body>

--===============4891318827246988476==--

INFO 0126 09:26:03.228621 client.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO 0126 09:26:03.228771 client.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: If you run with the debug flag on (gsutil -D -m cp -r ...), do you see any other information?

Comment: @TravisHobrla I tried to runt the command with `-D` at home but interestingly it worked fine. Tomorrow I'll tun from the office with this debug flag and edit my post.